# Reputation losses on Chemistry.SE - Can we please get the votes back?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, voting

The following illustrates the dramatic impact of a situation described earlier in

> [Don't throw away all votes when a user is deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125740/dont-throw-away-all-votes-when-a-user-is-deleted).

[Chemistry.SE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/) is a vivid beta site with ~ 2700 questions. The reputation of the Top 5 users lies between ~ 9500 and (curently) 4500. I'm the happy guy on rank 5, having given > 200 answers.

The community is quite active and the regulars do their best to prevent the site from degrading into some shabby do-my-homework forum.

When a prolific user (fellow scientist from another continent) decided to leave for personal reasons all his votes were wiped.

I can definitely confirm that he was neither kicked or forced to close his account. The answers and comments that he gave before show that he was a well-mannered person with both a passion for chemistry and Chemistry.SE, voting a lot to improve the site.

Fortunately, his answers and comments are still there - for good reason. Unfortunately, his votes were not measured according to the same standards and got wiped.

When he left, I personally lost **440** (9% of my total) reputation from upvotes on my answers on a single day (2014-03-21)!

**Admittedly, this annoys me a lot!** Others have lost accordingly.

As outlined above, Chemistry.SE is (still) small and the rules for keeping votes of leaving users with a reputation >> 10k simply can't be applied for our turf.

So: Can we please get the up- and downvotes by our former colleague and fellow scientist back?

Comment: Just support the existing feature request and start a bounty on it if you think it deserves more attention? This seems like a dupe to me.

Comment: @Bart would this be appropriate as an answer on that  question?

Comment: @JanDvorak if rephrased as such, pointing out the particular problematic nature on Beta sites, that might work.

Comment: @Bart Honestly, I had hoped for an individual (manual) solution to fix the "damage". Maybe, I just didn't make myself clear enough - usually I just write answers concerning chemistry.

Comment: @KlausWarzecha then that might be better for the Chemistry Meta? In any case, I've dumped a bounty on the "duplicate". And if rephrased, your question might work as an answer there.

Comment: @Bart I talked to one of the moderators on Chem before starting something bigger here. He told me - right or wrong - that he couldn't  do anything about the votes being wiped automatically.

Comment: That would seem to be correct. So you'd end up requesting a feature similar to the one in the duplicate. Hence my earlier comments.

Comment: @Klaus You would need the SE staff for that, but I have no idea if they'd actually consider it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer to that one is "nope" @animuson.

Comment: @Bart Sorry, I'm apparently a tad slow today. If one does view it that way (= as a request for an automated feature), one might indeed call it a duplicate and you are right.

Comment: @animuson That was my idea too, I just might have barked the wrong tree here ;)

Comment: I'll let others chime in there @KlausWarzecha, but I'm pretty hard pressed to believe that staff would consider a one-off rep loss reversal for a particular issue. Particularly given the precedent that would create. So it would  have to come as a feature request I'd assume.

Comment: Taking all this into account, shall I just wait for this question to be closed as a dupe or should I just delete it myself?

Comment: Well if your *only* focus here is the votes in this specific case, this belongs on Chemistry's Meta as it only applies to that site. The staff watch all Metas, so there's no need to come here to get their attention.

Comment: @animuson Honestly, my request really just concerned the incident on Chemistry - and I've blown off steam there already :D

Comment: possible duplicate of [Don't throw away all votes when a user is deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125740/dont-throw-away-all-votes-when-a-user-is-deleted)

Comment: @animuson I am under the impression that the reputation loss when a user is deleted is not something that the people running an SE site can change, short of modifying the server code. Such change means adding a feature to SE server code. If so, then would it not be the case that a request for restoring the reputation lost to another user's deletion in a *specific* case amounts to a request for a *SE-wide* feature and thus *this* forum would be the appropriate place for it? I'm trying to figure out where I'm erring here.

Comment: @Louis A request for a specific case would be a matter of finding all the votes that *were* attached to that user's account and making them active again. AFAIK the votes don't actually get *deleted* completely from the database, but just marked as "cleared" as if they had been retracted and assigned to the Community user (could be wrong there, I'd just be surprised if they were hard deleted). I'm not sure how manual of a process it really is to restore them, but you would not need to modify any existing feature to do so, as that update only occurs once upon deletion of the user.

Comment: @animuson Thanks for elucidating. I was indeed mistaken as to what it would mean for the people running the site.

Comment: @Bart OP posted an answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173045/wiping-votes-on-deletion-of-highly-active-accounts-865-points-on-user-was-rem) earlier today, but since it wasn't really an answer and more a request to reapply the votes, me and (I think it was) psubsee2003 suggested to post it as a question.

Comment: @Stijn yes I did suggest it and upon reflection, I probably shouldn't have phased in that way.  I was trying to encourage leaving the answer as I thought it was a decent answer to the issue just without the "can I get my rep back" question, but I think it came off as delete it and ask a question.   I agree this would be better on Meta.Chemistry or an email to the SE team.

Comment: @psubsee2003 My bad, I got you completely wrong then.

Comment: @KlausWarzecha don't worry about it, I led you down the wrong path, so that's my fault.

Comment: @psubsee2003 No problem. If we go to hell for that together, I'll buy you a coffee.

Comment: @KlausWarzecha I still think that if you remove the last sentence from that answer, it is a good answer on that question.  You should edit it out and undelete it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is, unfortunately, just how the system works: when an account is removed, so are the votes. This is probably not the last time you'll see this - fixing it would require some pretty massive changes to how voting (and user accounts) are implemented.

That said, we do have a system in place to preserve *some* votes when a high-ranking user is removed. As a result, you'll normally see only small changes to your reputation as folks depart. In this case however, they didn't kick in - I won't go into details, but the situation was somewhat unusual.

Expect to see reputation and post scores fluctuate over the next day or so as anomalies are corrected. I apologize for the disruption.

Comment: This is great news and I can absolutely live with with these fluctuations!

Comment: Well, I got my rep back. Thank you! :)

Comment: @tschoppi My pleasure! :)